# Why is my server getting connections from its own IP?

Tags: nginx, debian-buster

The most numerous connecting IP is my server's own IP.

It's Debian 10, Nginx, Mysql machine serving a single Wordpress and phpBB site. It's a virtual machine on Google's Cloud.

I'm obviously not too hot with this stuff, but good enough to build up a machine and have it serve the site.

```
$ sudo awk '{print $1}' /var/log/nginx/access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

returns

5122 **104.198.149.xxx**

4268 157.90.209.xxx

3752 93.158.90.xxx

1982 68.68.32.xxx

[...]

~ ~ ~

104.198.149.xxx is my server.

Output of

```
grep 104.198.149.xxx /var/log/nginx/access.log

162.158.252.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:00:25 -0700] "GET /forums/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12459 "https://104.198.149.xxx/forums" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible;Cloudflare-Healthchecks/1.0;+https://www.cloudflare.com/; healthcheck-id: bfa5d32ce9a5eaf8)"  
  
172.69.32.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:00:59 -0700] "GET /forums/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12471 "https://104.198.149.xxx/forums" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible;Cloudflare-Healthchecks/1.0;+https://www.cloudflare.com/; healthcheck-id: bfa5d32ce9a5eaf8)"  
  
104.198.149.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:01:00 -0700] "POST /wp/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1636614060.6961169242858886718750 HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "https://www.example.com/wp/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1636614060.6961169242858886718750" "WordPress/5.8.2; https://www.matthewsvolvosite.com"  
  
108.162.220.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:01:03 -0700] "GET /forums/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12465 "https://104.198.149.xxx/forums" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible;Cloudflare-Healthchecks/1.0;+https://www.cloudflare.com/; healthcheck-id: bfa5d32ce9a5eaf8)"  
  
104.198.149.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:01:07 -0700] "GET /forums/download/file.php?id=30434&amp;mode=view HTTP/1.0" 200 641193 "-" "-"  
  
104.198.149.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:01:07 -0700] "GET /forums/download/file.php?id=30435&amp;mode=view HTTP/1.0" 200 933139 "-" "-"  
  
104.198.149.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:01:10 -0700] "GET /forums/download/file.php?id=55475&amp;mode=view HTTP/1.0" 200 1015069 "-" "-"  
  
104.198.149.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:01:10 -0700] "GET /forums/download/file.php?id=55476&amp;mode=view HTTP/1.0" 200 933149 "-" "-"  
  
104.198.149.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:01:10 -0700] "GET /forums/download/file.php?id=55477&amp;mode=view HTTP/1.0" 200 916765 "-" "-"  
  
104.198.149.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:01:17 -0700] "GET /forums/download/file.php?id=30691&amp;mode=view HTTP/1.0" 200 121584 "-" "-"  
  
104.198.149.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:01:18 -0700] "GET /forums/download/file.php?id=30692&amp;mode=view HTTP/1.0" 200 137607 "-" "-"  
  
104.198.149.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:01:18 -0700] "GET /forums/download/file.php?id=30693&amp;mode=view HTTP/1.0" 200 133153 "-" "-"  
  
104.198.149.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:01:24 -0700] "GET /forums/download/file.php?id=33292&amp;mode=view HTTP/1.0" 200 949523 "-" "-"  
  
104.198.149.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:01:25 -0700] "GET /forums/download/file.php?id=33293&amp;mode=view HTTP/1.0" 200 1047827 "-" "-"  
  
104.198.149.xxx - - [11/Nov/2021:00:01:25 -0700] "GET /forums/download/file.php?id=33294&amp;mode=view HTTP/1.0" 200 916755 "-" "-"
```

Comment: Please add about ten lines from `grep 104.198.149.xxx /var/log/nginx/access.log` output to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you will see connections from your servers IP is usually due to using a reverse proxy. Over the years there has been changes to how this can be resolved.

The original way was using the X-Forwarded-For header. Then there was a standardised way of doing it with [RFC 7239](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7239) which is called Forwarded. Here is an [article from NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/) explaining this.

The final option is to use the proxy protocol. [HERE](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/) is the official documentation around this from NGINX.

To understand this all more in depth here is a [fantastic post](https://systemoverlord.com/2020/03/25/security-101-x-forwarded-for-vs-forwarded-vs-proxy.html) explaining it all.

Comment: Inside a location block inside /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com there is `fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY '';` Could that be doing it? There is no proxy anything in Nginx's config file. But there is `server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;
        location /nginx_status {
                stub_status on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
        }
}` in /etc/nginx/conf.d/stub_status.conf, which at least to me suggests the Nginx server is listening to itself.

Comment: Cipher, thanks for the links. But it's all over my head. I'm not (at least intentionally) running a proxy. There is no Apache on this machine processing the requests and sending to Nginx, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

This is an educated guess.

You have a WordPress plugin that somehow views files uploaded to the phpBB forum you have. Internally it downloads the file from phpBB, and then presents it via some WordPress -side page.